# Derivative of a exponential with a step

Tags: derivative

Given the following function: f(t) = e^-5(t-0.2). How do you take the derivative? Intuitively I think the function exists @ t = .2 and beyond. So I think you would take the derivative of f(t) = e^-5t.
f'(t) = -5 e^-5t.
I'm looking for some insight into the pure mathematics of this. Is this correct? If so, how do I justify this? Thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPwu2.png)

Comment: Which language is this in? I suspect that you may be better off asking in a maths group.

Comment: The language is English.  Sorry, Paul, I don't use an equation editor; MathStack won't let me copy in a copy of the equation using a math editor.  The equation in words is: the number "e" raised to -5 power times open parentheses t minus 0.2 closed parentheses. Will try to see if I can paste in a better version of the equation.

Comment: I meant programming language, since this is a software and programming site.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for clarification. I'm on the wrong board. Thanks again.